# AngularJS UI Grid, How to filter currency with $0.00

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am working with AngularJS UI-Grid and am trying to filter pricing.  The filtering works fine for anything with a number other than 0 behind the decimal.

```
$scope.GridOptions = {
            enableFiltering: true,
            rowEditWaitInterval: -1,
            multiSelect: true,
            enableColumnMenus: false,
            columnDefs: [
                { name: 'Name', field: 'Item', width: '15%' },
                { name: 'Price', field: 'Price', type: 'number', cellFilter: 'currency', width: '6%' },
                { name: 'Current Price', field: 'CurrentPrice', type: 'number', cellFilter: 'number: 2', width: '12%' }
            ]
```

[2 after decimal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kVJl.png), 
[0 after decimal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6YYC.png)

Comment: angular js has a built in currency filter.  in the template you can do something like {{item_price | currency}}, inside an ng-repeat if you need to (which it looks like you do)

Comment: It's reading it as currency, but it's still filtering out anything that would read '.0'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the field type to 'numberstr' per the documentation @ http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions.columnDef for the cell 'type' attribute

Comment: It's still losing anything that has a '.0' in the price (i.e. 0.00 or 10.05).  The moment you key in the decimal, it filters out anything that has a 0 behind the decimal.

Comment: -_- I have found the reason for the problem.  The CSV I am pulling from truncates the trailing 0's (so anything coming in as 0.00 or 10.00 will be just 0 or 10).  I am using AngularJS to append the .00 at the end but when you filter, UI-Grid ignores any graphical modifications it has done to the object.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thus js interpreting it as a string. You can always append the decimal with the parsefloat() function too

Answer (score 0):

I had to jump through way too many hoops to get a nice-looking currency column, but hopefully this will be accounted for in the future. This worked best for me:

JS - add `cellFilter:number:2` and `cellClass:'currency'` to the column definition:

```
myGrid.columnDefs = [{
    field: "Sale",
    cellFilter: 'number:2',
    cellClass:'currency'
}]
```

CSS - add these two style definitions to your css:

```
.currency{
    text-align:right;
}
.currency .ui-grid-cell-contents:before{
    content: '$';
    float: left;
}
```

Final result:

[image: The final currency column]

You can read more about it in my original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45601956/1152809).